# RF24 and Arduino Micro experience packet loss

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to setup two Arduino mircos, one as a receiver and one as a controller, to be a wireless remote for my media center.

The controller sends button combinations to the receiver.  The receiver then pushes the corresponding keyboard combinations.

I'm using the [RF24 library from ManiacBug](http://maniacbug.github.io/RF24/) with the Arduino micros and NRF24L01+ transceivers.

I would like to set the controller to stay in write mode and the receiver to stay in listening mode.  There isn't much of a reason to switch modes as the communication is one-way.  (I could add an auto-acknowledge to double check packets, but that's the point here.)

My issue is if I keep them each in there respective mode, the communication is very inconsistent and fails more often than not.

The code for the controller is

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
#include "printf.h"

RF24 radio(9,10);

// Radio pipe addresses for the 2 nodes to communicate.
const uint64_t pipes[2] = { 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL, 0xF0F0F0F0D2LL };

// button
const unsigned short nButtons = 2;
const unsigned short buttonPin[] = {6,7};

unsigned curr,prev;


unsigned short getButtons(const unsigned short nButtons,
              const unsigned short * const buttonPin);

unsigned short getButtons(const unsigned short nButtons,
              const unsigned short * const buttonPin){
  // write each button to a bit
  unsigned short i,buttons = 0,state;
  for(i = 0; i < nButtons; ++i){
    state = digitalRead(buttonPin[i]);
    if(state == HIGH){
      buttons |= (1u << i);
    }
  }
  return buttons;
}

void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(57600);
  printf_begin();

  radio.begin();

  // optionally, increase the delay between retries & # of retries
  radio.setRetries(15,15);

  // optionally, reduce the payload size.  seems to
  // improve reliability
  radio.setPayloadSize(sizeof(unsigned short));

  radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);

  unsigned short i;
  for(i = 0; i < nButtons; ++i)
    pinMode(buttonPin[i],INPUT);

  curr = prev = 0;
}



void loop(void){
  curr = getButtons(nButtons,buttonPin);

  if(curr != prev){
    printf("Buttons: %u\n\r",curr);

    bool ok = radio.write( &curr, sizeof(unsigned short) );
    prev = curr;

    if (ok)
      printf("sent.\n\r");
    else
      printf("failed.\n\r");

    // have to cycle listening otherwise communication fails
    radio.startListening();
    radio.stopListening();
  }
}
```

And the receiver is

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
#include "printf.h"

RF24 radio(9,10);

// Radio pipe addresses for the 2 nodes to communicate.
const uint64_t pipes[2] = { 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL, 0xF0F0F0F0D2LL };

const unsigned short nButtons = 2;
const unsigned short keys[] = {216, // left
                   215}; // right
const char* name[] = {"LEFT","RIGHT"};

unsigned short curr = 0,prev = 0;

void keyMap(const unsigned short curr, const unsigned short prev,
        const unsigned short nButtons){
  // map the button changes to keyboard commands

  unsigned short i,change;
  change = curr ^ prev;
  for(i = 0; i < nButtons; ++i){
    if((change & (1u << i)) && (curr & (1u << i))){
      printf("Press %s\n\r",name[i]);
      Keyboard.press(keys[i]);
    }
    else if(change & (1u << i)){
      printf("Release %s\n\r",name[i]);
      Keyboard.release(keys[i]);
    }
  }
}

void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(57600);
  printf_begin();

  radio.begin();

  // optionally, increase the delay between retries & # of retries
  radio.setRetries(15,15);

  // optionally, reduce the payload size.  seems to
  // improve reliability
  radio.setPayloadSize(sizeof(unsigned short));

  radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[0]);

  radio.startListening();

  Keyboard.begin();

  curr = prev = 0;
}

void loop(void){
  // if there is data ready
  if ( radio.available() ){
    // Dump the payloads until we've gotten everything
    unsigned short got_buttons;
    bool done = false;
    while (!done){
      // Fetch the payload, and see if this was the last one.
      done = radio.read( &got_buttons, sizeof(unsigned short) );
      curr = got_buttons;

      keyMap(curr,prev,nButtons);
      prev = curr;

      printf("Got payload %u.\n\r",got_buttons);
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is in the controller code.  I have to have `radio.startListening(); radio.stopListening();` otherwise the transmission fails almost every time.  If you remove those two statements, then the communication only goes through if you rapidly press a button.

I opened up the source code for these two methods and noticed they both call `flush_tx()` and `flush_rx()`.  Could it be that the buffers are filling up?  I'm not too familiar with this sort of thing, so not sure how to debug.

If you have any insight as to why I'm getting this behavior, or if you have any suggestions for debugging I would be very interested!

Answer (score 0):

Quite often problems with RF24s on Arduino are caused by the power supply to the modules as they may need a higher current than many of the arduinos can supply on the 3.3V line. Are they powered from the 3.3V on the arduino or du you have other power supplies for the modules? I am powering them from the 5V line from the arduino using a voltage regulator to get 3.3V. 
E.g. http://www.dx.com/p/ams1117-3-3-3v-power-module-boards-w-indicator-blue-5-pcs-163564#.Vqiu_43Sk-U or use pure ams1117 or similiar if you don't mind some soldering. It might also be that an approximate 10uF condenser over the supply lines i enough.